# How to make videos on Youtube not cover a lightbox?

Tags: javascript, dom, youtube

Edit: I thought I solved it but I didn't.

I have javascript that gathers elements on a webpage and puts them in a lightbox on top of the page. It works fine for your every day page but on Youtube the videos show through. I looked and found out about wmode = "transparent". So what I have tried is...

```
var youtubevideo = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
var len = youtubevideo.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    //youtubevideo[i].setAttribute('wmode', "transparent");
    youtubevideo[i].href += "?wmode=transparent";
    alert(youtubevideo[i].href);
}
```

The alert verifies I am doing nothing wrong as far as doing what I intend to do. You can also see where I have commented out the other way I tried it. Is there a way I didn't find to accomplish this?

Comment: So answer your own question and mark it solved!

Comment: @epascarello Not allowed to yet. Also, I was wrong. It ended up pushing the video down and it looked like it was behind it but it wasn't.

Comment: `?wmode=...` should work (unless you've added other parameters, in which case you have to use `&wmode=...`, of course). Don't use "transparent", though. If it works with "transparent" it should work with "opaque", and the only thing you get out of "transparent" for this is lower performance and more - unpredictable - bugs.

Comment: @TheKaneda neither works. The video still stays above everything. I had already added max zIndex to all my stuff as well.

Comment: Yeah, z-index will make no difference - the problem (usually) is that for performance reasons, FlashPlayer displays any content in an overlay "window" on top of the browser window (`wmode="window"`), unless you change that wmode. Two possibilities: New wmode bugs in newer versions of FlashPlayer (it had around 200 unsolved ones last I checked), or YouTube decided to ignore the parameter recently (they might, since there are new wmodes in 10 and 11 for direct hardware access and GPU rendering). Have you checked in a DOM inspector if the `wmode` param is actually added to the `<object>`?

Comment: @TheKaneda I am doing inspect element in chrome and seeing that it is being added to what I have made it get added to. Do you think I could be adding it to the wrong thing? Do you have an idea of what I should be adding it to if I am?

Comment: Well, it should have a `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` (or "transparent") inside an `<object>` element for FlashPlayer to use the value. In some browsers a `wmode="opaque"` may still be needed inside an `<embed>` element. Both are something YouTube should be adding when you have an embed URL with `?wmode=opaque/transparent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you need to make the video reload. You can do this by copying the src to another variable then change the src to "" and then change the src again to the variable you saved the original src in.