# How can I prevent one from being able to right click on flash embed

Tags: javascript, flash, menu

I need to suppress the default right click menu for flash embeds.

I've set menu to false, as well as used a stop default function on the right click event, but it still displays the menu.

Also, I don't have access to the .fla's, as the flash objects weren't created by me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The next version of Flash Player, 11.2, that is currently in release candidate state, will let you hide the right click menu, but in older versions it is not possible.

Comment: why?  A little more about they might offer more suggestions if @TheKaneda's answer is not good for you.

Answer (score 1):

Without the fla's (and altering those wouldn't even give you what you want anyway), you'd need to do something to cover up the swf file in the HTML - e.g., a `<div>`.

This, however, would also block any left clicks, and if you don't want that, the only way I know of (and I'm quite sure it *is* the only way, safe variations) is to make code additions in order to get the left clicks through. It's a hack anyway - even more than the swf-covering `<div>` is in the first place.

In order to cover the swf, its window mode (`wmode` param) needs to be set to "opaque" (or "transparent" if areas inside the swf need to be transparent). Both change the render mode of FlashPlayer so that HTML can be displayed on top of it (the default `wmode="window"` causes it to render on top of anything else). Both alternative `wmode` params lower performance somewhat ("transparent" more so than "opaque"), and both introduce certain unpredictable and seemingly unrelated bugs in FlashPlayer (again, "transparent" more so than "opaque"). E.g. YouTube do support changing the wmode param, so in their case, it should be bug free - but others have had troubles getting it to work. See e.g. [How to make videos on Youtube not cover a lightbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321265/how-to-make-videos-on-youtube-not-cover-a-lightbox)

After setting the `wmode` to "transparent", you can place a `<div>` absolutely to cover the swf, which means it'll capture the left clicks before they reach the swf. Remember that IE6-8 will not capture clicks on an element that is transparent, though - so you'd need a color + alpha = 0 - or a transparent png/gif - for the background of the element.

As a side note, just to cover the concept of letting left clicks pass through to the swf (which requires additions in the source code/fla): You'd basically let the `<div>` capture the mousedown events, and pass the coordinates on to Flash via `ExternalInterface`. Could do the same for right clicks. This allows - and is the only way, even if it's very, extremely hacky - to make e.g. special right click functionality for Flash, rather than showing its context menu.

Until FlashPlayer 11.2, that is. It adds support for right/middle clicks - as well as locking the mouse etc. (but it's still unlikely that you could do so without access to the source).

In any event, unless you *really* need this (and there *are* such cases), it's a better idea to find alternatives - even if not *quite* as bad an idea as disabling the right click menu on a webpage in general.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Builder:

```
var myContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
myContextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
```

Comment: He said he doesn't have access to the .fla's. Are you trying to embed youtube videos or something? More details would be great.

Comment: @Tyler: yep, think the OP edited the question while I was typing my answer. Or perhaps I missed that part.